# Thymeleaf cache set to false not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a spring application under development. 
The configuration of the project is as follows:

- spring-dev-tools dependency is one of the maven dependencies
- thymeleaf dependency is added through spring-boot-starter, that is `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`
- I have explicitly disabled template cache with `spring.thymeleaf.cache=false`
- The `src/main/resources` folder is marked as resource in my IntelliJ IDEA project.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA project to run the application.
When I run the application, I can see in the console output that: `LiveReload server is running on port 35729`
Although, it seems like all my configuration is correct, the running application is not loading any changes I made to the templates while it is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LiveReload server loads any changes only when one of the files on the classpath is modified [Spring Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart).
Though I have resources, the folder containing templates folder, on the classpath, the changes to the html files in templates folder are not reflected in the running application.
What worked for me is to also add `src/main/resources/templates` to the classpath i.e. marked as resource in IntelliJ

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `Spring Tool Suite 4`, you need to implement the following in your `application.properties` to disable the `cache` from `Thymeleaf`:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:src/main/resources/templates/
```

Adding the `spring.thymeleaf.prefix` value worked for me.

For more information about the solution:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34#issuecomment-316295791

Answer (score 0):

for me adding these two properties worked:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=file:src/main/resources/templates/
```

i am on STS 4.20.1